# Magento Category Products suck on "Reindex Required"

Tags: magento-1.9

After a clean `Magento 1.9` install/deployment using `Microsoft Azure web app` from gallery, the **Category Products** is stuck on **Reindex required**

Clicking the reindex button, I just get the error

> There was a problem with reindexing process.

No products or data has been added.

How do I solve this?

Comment: From /var/log/exception.log

Answer (score -1):

execute the following from the command line:

> php /path/to/magento/shell/indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: This is more of a suggestion than an answer, please add as comment